# a jQuery promise that always succeeds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have this code jQuery code fragment:

```
$.get('/api/' + currentPage).done(function(data) { ... })
                            .fail(...)
```

I want to replace `$.get('/api/'+currentPage)` with a promise that always succeeds and returns a specific value for `data`. Something like:

```
let myData = { ... }  // value of data I want to pass to the done function

(new AlwaysSucceeds(myData)).done(function(data) { ... })
                            .fail(...)
```

I could cobble up a dummy object, or I could extract out the `done` function but I want to keep changes to the code to a minimum.

Is there a way to do this?

UPDATE: To help clarify what's going, the code I am working with is [(here)](https://github.com/LilyBin/LilyBin/blob/1df09dc1d83707d79fb91a6c77ce27ae819a3680/htdocs/js/main.js#L207). Normally this app is served from a nodejs server which implements the `/api/...` call, but I am converting it to be served
from a static page server. I know what is going to be returned from
the `$.get` call. To keep changes to the code clean I simply want to
change that line to:

```
let myData = {...}

// $.get('/api/' + currentPage) -- comment out the $.get call
(SOMETHINGHERE(myData)).done(function(data) {
```

The `SOMETHINGHERE` expression needs to implement `.done(f)`
which will call the function `f` with `myData` and then return
some object which implements `.fail(...)` which does nothing.

Comment: What about `.always()` ? `get()` is an ajax method, so isn't it impossible to expect it to be done succesfully, always? So.. if you can't then maybe `always()` might be a help?

Comment: I guess I could make that work. I'd prefer not to perform the `$.get()` at all, although I could change the url to something innocuous.

Comment: You can replace `$.get()` with anything that returns a promise that is resolved with the data you already have.  It's really not clear at all here what problem you're trying to actually solve.  If you already have the data, why are you even using a promise at all?  That's just a synchronous operation then.  No promises needed.  Question seems unclear to me.

Comment: @jfriend00 It's useful if you have a function with signature `args -> Promise<T>` (i.e. returns a promise), where it needs to return a promise in certain cases, but can resolve immediately in other cases. For the simplicity of the caller, the function should always return a promise.

Comment: @mc10 - I get that for a general purpose API design, but that isn't what appears to be going on here.  The OP has the whole chain of code.  They don't have to just replace the first part of it - they could just fix up the whole piece since they already have the data synchronously.

Comment: @mc10 You mean something like `Promise.resolve` The jQuery object isn't really a promise because it has `done`, `always` and some other things you don't need because you can do with `then`. When combining non promises with promises it's saver to only assume it has `then` and work with a bunch of `thenables`

Comment: @HMR Sorry, I'm using Promise and Deferred interchangeably; interpret my last message with `s/Promise/Deferred`.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've updated the question with some more background details. Looks like `$.when()` will work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just replace `$.get(...)` with a function that returns a promise that is already resolved with the data you already have.  And, the shortest way to get an already resolved jQuery promise, resolved with a particular value, is this:

```
$.when(myData).done(...)
```

The more text book way to do it in jQuery is:

```
$.Deferred().resolve(myData).done(...)
```

And, if you care to switch your logic to the the ES6 standard (instead of the non-standard jQuery promise behaviors), then you could use this:

```
Promise.resolve(myData).then(...).catch(...)
```

Comment: Sadly the jQuery Deferred has some things that native promises don't have, when combining library non standard promises with native promises it's best to only assume they have `then`. OP is using `done` and `fail` but those are not things a native promise has.

Comment: @HMR - Since the OP controls the whole promise chain of code here, I'm showing them how they could just switch to ES6 promises to solve this whole issue with that.  Jquery 3.x has a lot of compatibility with ES6 promises if you choose to use it and stick with `.then()`.  Personally, I NEVER code with the jQuery specific `.done()` and `.fail()` because it really messes you up when you use ES6 behaviors elsewhere since the two do not work the same way.  Anyway, I included the ES6 signature for completeness and the OP can choose.  There are two other jQuery options if that's what the OP wants.

Comment: I added an answer warning about libraries non standard promises. Not just the non standard methods they have but non especially standard behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by implementing `AlwaysSuceeds` constructor function. Please see below example.

```js
function AlwaysSucceeds(data) {
  this.data = data; 
}

AlwaysSucceeds.prototype.done = function(fn) {
  fn(this.data);
  return this;
}

AlwaysSucceeds.prototype.fail = function(fn) {
  return this;
}


var myData = { 
  a: 1 
};

(new AlwaysSucceeds(myData)).done(function(data) { 
  console.log(data)
}).fail(function(data){ 

})
```

Comment: Yeah - this is what I was going to do if I couldn't find a jQuery solution!

Answer (score 1):

Since jQuery Ajax functions just return [`$.Deferred`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) objects, you can just substitute an immediately-resolved `Deferred`:

```
$.Deferred().resolve(myData).then(...)
```

In this particular case, if you want to make it easy to switch between synchronous and asynchronous code, and you have access to `async`/`await`, you can just use those directly:

```
try {
    const data = await Promise.resolve($.get('/api/' + currentPage));
    // code in done
} catch (err) {
    // code in fail
}
```

would become

```
try {
    const data = myData;
    // code in done
} catch (err) {
    // code in fail (never runs unless other code throws exceptions)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you actually want but be carufull using jQuery Deferred with native promises, the deferred has some non standard methods that native promises don't have.

So to be save I always assume there is a `thenable`, something that has a `then` with that you can pretty much do whatever you want.

jQuery Deferred do not behave like native promises either (depending on version):

```
$.Deferred().reject("hello world")
.then(
  undefined
  ,x=>x
)
.then(
  x=>console.log("Never happens",x)
)

Promise.reject("hello world")
.then(
  undefined
  ,x=>x
);
.then(
  x=>console.log("Well behaved",x)
);

Promise.resolve().then(x=>{throw "nope"})
.then(undefined,err=>console.warn(err));

$.Deferred().resolve().then(x=>{throw "nope"})//crashes
.then(undefined,err=>err);
```

So it will be saver to use native promises and polyfill with something that behaves like native.

To answer the question about non failing promise, if you want to make a request but return a default when it rejects and keep returning the same once resolves or rejects you can do:

```
const get = (p=>{
  (url) => {
    p = p ||
    //return native promise or properly polyfilled one
    Promise.resolve($.get(url))
    .then(
      undefined,
      _=> {defaultobject:true}
    );
    return p;
  }
})();
```

Your get function will return a native promise so no `fail`, `done` and other things that are non standard. Combining "promises" from different libraries and native promises it would be best to only use `then`

Comment: I have no idea how this relates to the actual question.  In an ES6 world, interoperability is best achieved by just casting a foreign promise to a known, ES6 promise by wrapping it in `Promise.resolve()`.  But, none of that actually seems relevant to the question the OP asked and we needn't make a bigger sidetrack than you already have here.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't know what the question is. Does the OP want something like `Promse.resolve` or a function that has a non rejectable `$.get` that's only called once. Then OP uses `jQuery.Defered` a sure way to shoot yourself in the foot when combining your promise chain with native and other libraries promises.

Comment: Hmmm.  You don't know what the question is, but you've written an answer?  OK, I guess I'll stop commenting on it then.

Comment: `I want to replace $.get('/api/'+currentPage) with a promise that always succeeds and returns a specific value for data.` How do you interpret that? Either want `Promise.all` or unrejectable `$.get` but since $.get can reject have a default value for that.

Comment: I thought I understood the question so I wrote an answer for how to replace `$.get()` with something that returns a jQuery promise that always resolves (or switch to an ES6 standard syntax if they wish).   You can see that in my answer (I think you've already seen it).  That part seemed pretty simple to me.  Your answer appears to be a diatribe on promise compatibility issues which does not seem to have anything to do with the question at all.

Comment: Probably Erik was looking `Promise.resolve` or `$.Deferred().resolve` but I was in a situation some time ago where a rejecting `$.ajax` has to return an alternative/default and `.then(throw)` crashed my code as well as `.then(
  undefined
  ,x=>x
)` would not continue the promise chain. Since Erik may be looking for something like that in a legacy app (update jQuery not possible) I thought I'd add the answer. Did not mention `Promise.resolve` since you already added that possibility.